# Calling stored proc that has default value parameters

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, vbscript

I have a stored procedure with signature

```
PROCEDURE store_cust_response(
    p_id NUMBER DEFAULT NULL, 
    p_camp_id NUMBER DEFAULT NULL, 
    p_offer_id NUMBER DEFAULT NULL
)
```

When creating parameters in VBSCript, do I have to create one for each parameter in the signature? If so, how do I then invoke their default values?

```
Set conncmdA = CreateObject("adodb.command")
conncmdA.CommandText = "foo.store_cust_response"
conncmdA.CommandType = 4    'adCmdStoredProc
conncmdA.ActiveConnection = conntemp

conncmdA.Parameters.Append conncmdA.CreateParameter("p_id", adInteger, adParamInput, 4)
conncmdA.Parameters.Append conncmdA.CreateParameter("p_camp_id", adInteger, adParamInput, 4)
conncmdA.Parameters.Append conncmdA.CreateParameter("p_offer_id", adInteger, adParamInput, 4)

conncmdA.Parameters(0) = null
conncmdA.Parameters(1) = camp_id
conncmdA.Parameters(2) = offer_id

conncmdA.Execute
Set conncmdA = Nothing
```

Comment: Have you tried something like this `store_cust_response(p_id => 324)`? if you invoke the procedure like this, p_camp_id and p_offer_id will have their default values. Also you can invoke like `store_cust_response(p_id => 324, p_offer_id => 432)` and the parameter `p_camp_id` will have its default value.

Comment: @zaratustra: I need to call the stored proc from VBScript, please see my edit to original post.

Comment: Could you please show us how you invoke your stored procedure? There has to be one more line above the code you have already shown.

Comment: It is all shown in the original post, the rest is boilerplate code. I'll edit the original post, for completeness.

Comment: IIRC default values are only applied if the procedure is invoked from PL/SQL. (My understanding is that the PL/SQL compiler grabs the default values from the data dictionary if the particular invocation of the procedure in PL/SQL doesn't supply all the parameters). If you're invoking the procedure some other way you have to supply all parameters. As far as "invoke their default values" - you can't. You have to supply values, even if those values are the same as the defaults in the signature. I suppose you could query the data dictionary too. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis, I had to list all the parameters, regardless of their default values. Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC default values are only applied if the procedure is invoked from PL/SQL. (My understanding is that the PL/SQL compiler grabs the default values from the data dictionary if the particular invocation of the procedure in PL/SQL doesn't supply all the parameters). If you're invoking the procedure some other way you have to supply all parameters. As far as "invoke their default values" - you can't. You have to supply values, even if those values are the same as the defaults in the signature. I suppose you could query the data dictionary to obtain the default values - something like

```
SELECT a.DEFAULT_VALUE
  FROM SYS.DBA_ARGUMENTS a
  WHERE a.OBJECT_NAME = whatever AND
        a.ARGUMENT_NAME = whatever;
```

One problem with this is that DBA_ARGUMENTS.DEFAULT_VALUE is a LONG (similar to a BLOB but more annoying to deal with) which you'd have to fetch and interpret.

Best of luck.